# Is it possible to assign ids to the parent of a spring:message tag when the page loads?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I currently have this snippet of code on my jsp page.

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <p>
    <spring:message code="help.${entry.key}"htmlEscape="false"/>
  </p>
</div>
```

The spring message section will be replaced by text from a properties file. Thats grand and all but is there way to preserve the value of the `code` attribute and place it in the parent tag after or when the page is loading? Like this for example

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <p id="help.some.thing.else">
    Hello, World!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can have `label` tag(`<label id="xxxxx"><spring:message code="help.${entry.key}" /></label`) and give id to that,and using that get the parent and manipulate

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to **re-use** the localized value of certain message key in different parts in your JSP page (Including tag attributes), it is possible by adding **"var"** attribute to the spring message tag:

```
<spring:message code="help.${entry.key}" var="helpMessage"/>

<div class="panel-body">
    <p id="${helpMessage}">
      Hello, World!
    </p>
</div>
```

Now, you can put **${helpMessage}** on any place inside your JSP page and it will be replaced by its value.

**Update**:

If you wanna to replace the content of certain tag (div in your case) by the value linked to the **raw key name** ***(as seen on your example above)*** that assigned to "id" attribute.

Then you have to use customized tags which receives the key on behalf of "id" then printing the extracted value into the body tag.

For more information on this topic read this Chapter: [Custom Tags in JSP Pages](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html)

Comment: My apologies for not being clear enough. My thinking is when the page loads the `<spring:message code="help.${entry.key}" var="helpMessage"/>` tag will be replaced by text. Want I want to do is to retrieve message key for text that has already been loaded.

Comment: @user36262 Please have a look to the updated answer.